# Finding optimal weighted average

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools

Constraints require multiplying every ingredient `amount` by the same factor where the nutrition of all ingredients combined must be within the minimum and maximum nutrition, whilst the optimal solution being the sum closest to the min/max median.

I've normalized the weight to be per gram, so to calculate the nutrients for an ingredient I do `amount[g] * ingredients[2][nutrient]`.

Ground beef nutrients sum:

```
calorie : 226.79616 * [ingredients][0][0] = 288.0311232
fat     : 226.79616 * [ingredients][0][1] = 22.679616
carb    : 226.79616 * [ingredients][0][2] = 0
protein : 226.79616 * [ingredients][0][3] = 19.470450336
```

All the ingredients nutrients combined results:

```
calorie: 575.8359139999999
fat: 48.160351846999994
carb: 3.842780537
protein: 37.289324852
```

`scalingMin` = 557.7/575.8359139999999 = 0.96850506618

`scalingMax` = 669.24/575.8359139999999 = 1.16220607942

The optimal scaling based on just the calorie would be `1.06453936807`, so all ingredients must be multiplied by the same scaling factor.

Here's the code I've written so far, but I'm not sure how to go about these constraints.

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

# get nutrients sum
def getNutritionalSumOfAllIngredients(list):
  numbs = [type for type in range(0, 4)]
  for key, ingredient in enumerate(list):
    for type, nutrient in enumerate(ingredient[2]):
      numbs[type] += (ingredient[1] * nutrient)
  return numbs

def main():
  nutrients = [
    ['calorie', 557.7, 669.24],
    ['fat', 39.04, 51.43],
    ['carb', 0, 13],
    ['protein', 31.19, 41.59]
  ]

  # name, amount (grams), [calorie, fat, net_carbs, protein] weight per gram
  ingredients = [
    ['ground beef', 226.79616, [1.27, 0.1, 0, 0.08585000000000001]],
    ['salt', 6.083333333333333, [0, 0, 0, 0]],
    ['black pepper', 1.0374999999999999, [1.255 , 0.0163, 0.19325, 0.05195]],
    ['cajun seasoning', 4, [0.46604999999999996, 0.010249999999999999, 0.06565, 0.0191]],
    ['mozzarella cheese', 28.34952, [1.5, 0.11175, 0.01095, 0.11085]],
    ['cheddar cheese', 56.69904, [2.02, 0.16655, 0.015449999999999998, 0.11435000000000001]],
    ['butter', 14.1875, [3.585, 0.40555, 0.0003, 0.00425]],
    ['cooked bacon', 28, [2.74, 0.21635000000000001, 0.006750000000000001, 0.17864999999999998]]
  ]
  
  solver = pywraplp.Solver('ScaleIngredients', pywraplp.Solver.GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING)

  # # sum of all ingredients nutrition must be within each nutrients min/max i.e [557.7, 669.24, 'calorie']
  objectives = [solver.NumVar(item[1], item[2], item[0]) for item in nutrients]

  test = getNutritionalSumOfAllIngredients(ingredients)
  print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

CP-SAT is a pure integral solver. It only emulates continuous variables.